# Поиск в массиве объектов ключей, содержащих два слова

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы

Всем привет!

Только учусь JavaScript, столкнулся со следующей задачей: в программе задана переменная `users`, которая хранит в себе массив. Элементы данного массива являются объектами. Требуется определить индекс элемента, значение свойства `role` которого содержит больше одного слова. Результат вывести в консоль разработчика.

Пробую следующий код, но не подходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так - как-будто упустил какой-то момент при обучении. Буду рад уяснить и выучить, что упускаю:

```js
const users = [{
    login: "user1",
    role: "Admin"
  },
  {
    login: "user2",
    role: "State user"
  },
  {
    login: "user3",
    role: "Moderator"
  }
];

function findSpace(users) {
  if (users.role.includes(/\s/)) {
    return users.role
  }
}
console.log(users.findIndex(findSpace));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.prototype.includes(аргумент не может быть регулярным выражением)
Можно просто изменить регулярное выражение на пробел (это самое примитивное решение)

```
function findSpace(user) {
    return user.role.includes(' ');
}
```

Более хороший способ будет выглядеть так, данное регулярное выражение будет сопоставлять любую последовательность символов без пробелов (здесь есть нюанс в том, что если строка будет пустая то `String.prototype.match()` - вернет null и вызов null.length даст ошибку):

```
function findSpace(user) {
    return user.role.match(/\S+/g).length > 1;
}
```

Чтобы избежать ошибки из примера выше, можно использовать `String.prototype.split()`:

```
function findSpace(user) {
    return user.role.split(/\b\W+\b/).length > 1;
}
```

**UPD**
P.S. Всё написанное выше, преследует исключительно научно-просветительные цели =))

Судя по комментариям автора, возникли некоторые сложности, вот ваш рабочий вариант, то что нужно скопировать к себе в файл:

```
const users = [
    { login: 'user1', role: 'Admin' },
    { login: 'user2', role: 'State user' },
    { login: 'user3', role: 'Moderator' },
];
function findSpace(user) {
    return user.role.split(/\b\W+\b/).length > 1;
}
console.log(users.findIndex(findSpace));
```

Comment: спасибо, но код не компилируется. Выдает следующее: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'users' has already been declared в первой строке.

Comment: Identifier 'users' has already been declared - переменная users уже объявлена, значит у вас в коде дважды объявлена переменная users

Comment: я это понимаю, но не вижу где. Можете подсказать?

Comment: Я не вижу экран вашего компьютера и то, что у Вас в редакторе. Создайте отдельный файл, скопируйте туда код из ответа и попробуйте. Либо откройте ваш файл нажмите `Ctrl+f` для поиска и введите название переменной users - так вы увидите где у вас встречается данная переменная. Если вы работаете в VScode у вас должен линтер подчеркивать повторное объявление одной и той же переменной

Comment: наглядный пример https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-frog-qq48bc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Никак не могу понять, для чего `return users`?

Comment: @Maxim, я вставляю в редактор только ту часть кода, которую вы написали. Больше ничего, весь код сразу начинается с объявления массива

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey поправил)

Comment: @Nikita в VScode работает, в codesandbox работает, а у Вас нет, не находите странным?) перепроверьте то что у вас в файле ещё раз